# How to fix an incorrectly working eyes texture?

Tags: rendering, texturing, 3d-view

I found a problem with incorrect display of eye texture. In Texture Paint, everything works fine if Viewport Shading is solid. But in Material Preview and Rendered, the sclera of the eye becomes gray, along with the eyeball. How can this be fixed?

I have absolutely no idea what needs to be done so that the texture of the eyes does not disappear.

[image: What the texture looks like:]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like transparency is not enabled. This is needed for the material preview and Eevee render modes. The cornea should be transparent and glossy. Check the material tab > *Settings > Blend Mode*. The mode should be *Alpha Hashed*

Comment: @Blunder 
Yes, I have already used this setting. Nothing changes.

Comment: That's good. And the nodes of the material that should be transparent are set up properly? The alpha mask should be connected to the *Alpha* slot of the *Principled BSDF*. This is either a separate image or the channel of the base color or another image when the textures are channel-packed. Later is often used for game models. I've seen imported models where the material was messed up, especially the transparency. The *Backface Culling* option in the material settings can cause problems, too.

Comment: Another thing: Have you enabled Screenspace Reflections?

Comment: @Blunder I enable Screenspace Reflections, but it also didn't give any results.

Comment: @Blunder I'm not sure about nodes of the material. 
I just started studying the program, so I don't understand many things. Nodes of the material were loaded automatically along with the model.

Comment: Can you show your node setup for the material of the eye that should be transparent? Or maybe share the file so we can have a look?

Comment: @Blunder 
I didn't understand if it was possible to upload files here and how to do it, so I uploaded a file in .blender format to this site. I hope everything will function.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/a38z78hlk7zwi8j/head.blend/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Eevee Render Settings**

First, enable
`[X]` *Ambient Occlusion* and
`[X]` *Screen Space Reflection* and
*[X] Screen Space Reflection >* `[X]` *Refraction*
in Eevee's render settings.

**Material For The Eyes**

Almost all materials have set *Metallic* to 1. For human models, this is not recommended. Set *Metallic* to `0`.

The eyes of the model consist of 4 mesh parts and the related material:

[image: part of the eyes]

1. the *cornea*, (*Material #67*). It covers the eyeball and is like a ball of glass. Settings:

   - *Base Color* = white
   - *Roughness* = `0`
   - *Transmission* = `1`
   - *Alpha* = `1`
   - in the *Material Properties*, enable *Settings > `[X]` Screen Space Reflections* to make them transmissive.
2. *faked amibient occlusion* (AO), (*Material #66*). It's a shadow near the eyelids inside the eye. This is needed for Eevee and game engines because there is a limitation that does not allow the add AO on transmissive materials such as the cornea. Settings:

   - *Base Color* = black or an image texture (*Map #2*?)
   - *Alpha* = an image texture or the *Alpha* slot of an image texture (*Map #2*?)
   - in the *Material Properties*, set *Settings > Blend Mode* to `Alpha Hashed`.
3. the *tear line*, (*Material #68*). It's tinted green in the screenshot so you can see it better. Usually, it's transmissive. Settings:

   - same as the cornea
   - Eevee cannot render transmissive & transparent glass (tear line) on glass (cornea). You can add transparency when you lower *Alpha* to `0.4`.
   - in the *Material Properties*, set *Settings > Blend Mode* to `Alpha Hashed`.
4. the *eyeball*, (*Eye_Mat*). It includes the pupil. Settings:

   - lower *Specular*, and maybe leave *Roughness* at `0.5`? Set *Metallic* to `0`.

You had not included the textures, so here is just a very rough example. (Eyebrows and eyelashes are usually also transparent.)

[image: material preview]